# Where does open office writer save its default template

Tags: windows-registry, openoffice, openoffice-writer, default-settings

Does anybody know where Openoffice saves its configuration for standard font, size etc?

I know i can create a template which gets used as a standard for new documents, but how do i get the location of this template? could not find it in the registry? and there is no default name like MSWord's normal.dotm, Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configutration/modification file is located at

```
%APPDATA%\OpenOffice.org\3\user\registrymodifications.xcu
```

The file is in XML format and is writtern in one line, therefore difficult to read.

Search for

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Office.Writer/DefaultFont">
```

And you can find the default font value for OpenOffice Writer

Comment: This is the only correct answer iv got about this in both stack exchange sites, thank you.